# MAX() value on a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, datediff

I have 2 tables, one with a set of proposals and one with votes cast on the proposals, both joined with a unique ID.

The proposals table has a date field when the proposal was started, the votes have a date when the vote was cast. The proposal is marked as "success" when enough votes are cast. I want to find out how many days it takes in average to close votes.

My initial approach was to create a query that lists each proposal with the most recent vote through a left join:

```
SELECT proposals.pr_id, DATEDIFF(MAX(proposals_votes.`date`), proposals.`date`)
FROM proposals
LEFT JOIN proposals_votes ON proposals.pr_id = proposals_votes.pr_id
WHERE STATUS = 'success'
```

The issue is that this returns only one line, which is a surprise to me. I would have thought the MAX is done on the LEFT JOIN table and not on the resulting table.

Is there a way to do this within the LEFT JOIN or do I need to do a sub-query?

Comment: You forgot `GROUP BY proposals.pr_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` clause on **pr_id** to fetch **no of days** for each **proposals**

Try this:

```
SELECT p.pr_id, DATEDIFF(MAX(pv.`date`), p.`date`)
FROM proposals p 
LEFT JOIN proposals_votes pv ON p.pr_id = pv.pr_id
WHERE pv.status = 'success'
GROUP BY p.pr_id;
```

Comment: Thanks. I somehow had the notion that GROUP BY rather groups the result of the query above instead of influencing the way MAX() is applied. Great insight.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multiple line you should use GROUP BY because of aggregate function always return only one rows. You will get multiple rows result by GROUP BY parameter like GROUP BY proposals.pr_id.

```
SELECT 
    proposals.pr_id,
    DATEDIFF(MAX(proposals_votes.date),proposals.date)
FROM
    proposals
        LEFT JOIN
    proposals_votes ON proposals.pr_id = proposals_votes.pr_id
WHERE
    STATUS = 'success'
GROUP BY proposals.pr_id;
```